# "For" in Label Tags

Tags: html, css

```
 <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
```

I was trying to Learn WP widgets creation. on the Tutorial websites this was Published -

Title

```
<p>
  <label for="message">Simple Message</label>
  <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="message" name="message">message...</textarea>

</p>
```

I am confused with this portion - 
for="message"

What does this means "message" is just a like class or ID that will be styled in CSS? Or I am not rightly informed?

Comment: Sir, I searched I couldn't find the question asked before can you Please help me with the Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` of the `<label>` references to the id of the`<textarea>` (message). If you then click on the label, the focus is set to the `<textarea>` with the respective id.

You can also wrap the textarea with the `<label>`. Then, you can click on every element or text inside the `<label>` and the focus is also set to the `<textarea>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I want to understand it better then is it a CSS territory or an HTML Territory?

Comment: It is a default behavior of HTML. Usually, such effects are made with JavaScript, but this one is provided by the browser per default. CSS is necessary for styling a page (but also used for animations and transitions), but you cannot use it for click-behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the label is for a specific form input element: in your case, the textarea with the `id` of `message`, or the radio button with the `id` of `male`.

When a label is for a specific input element, clicking on the label works like clicking on the input itself: clicking on the label for the radio button will select the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

An id uniquely identifies an element. A class marks an element as part of a group.

You can write CSS to match an element based on its class or its id.

You can write JavaScript to find an element based on its class or its id.

You can put `#an_id` on the end of a URL to link directly to an element based on its id.

You can associate a `<label>` with a form control by specifying the id of the form control in the `for` attribute.

Classes and IDs are an HTML thing, not something specific to CSS. They have many purposes.